# How can I retrieve a JPEG image codec in F#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, jpeg

In C#, I can retrieve a JPEG encoder like this:

```
var jpegEncoder = 
    ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        .Where(e => e.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
        .Single();
```

I'd like to do the same in thing F# and I know there's a beautifully succinct way to do it, but I'm just starting out and I can't quite figure it out. I see there's a Where method available hanging off of `GetImageEncoders()` but I can't figure out what to pass into it. I read [Don Syme's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/01/27/fsharpmeetslinqone.aspx) on F# and LINQ, but I just don't have enough experience in F# to really understand it.

Is there a nice way I can do this same thing in F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#r "System.Drawing"
open System.Drawing.Imaging
let jpeg = 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders() 
    |> Seq.find (fun e -> e.FormatID = ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
```

Comment: @ChaosPandion: `GetImageEncoders` calls [the native Windows function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534080(v=vs.85).aspx) of the same name. The available encoders, I assume, are system dependent.